# How to get a child node value based on another child in the same group

Tags: c#-4.0, xpath

I'm developing in C#, and am processing xml from an external soap call.
I have loaded the xml response into an XElement.

Given the following xml stub

```
<record>
   <node>
       <a>My title</a>
       <name>title_en</name>
   </node>
   <node>
      <a>...</a>
      <name>contact_name</name>
   </node>
   .....
</record>
```

Using xpath in C#: I'm trying to do the follow when using the method XPathSelectElement.

where

```
\record\node\name == 'title_en' select \record\node\a
```

If there is a better method to use or another suggestion on how to preform the query, I'm open to ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The xpath `/record/node[name = 'title_en']/a` would get the relevant element.

Comment: P.S. It's not clear what this question has to do with XSLT, maybe consider retagging.

Comment: @IanRoberts I removed the XSLT tag. I was looking at code while writing this questions and I added it my mistake. cheers

Comment: @IanRoberts Your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: another xpath is `/record/node/a[following-sibling::name[. = 'title_en']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *predicate* to constrain which node elements you need:

```
/record/node[name = 'title_en']/a
```

You read this expression as "find the record element, find all its child elements named `node` that have a `name` child with value "title_en", and for each of those find all `a` children"

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var title = doc.Descendants("node")
               .Where(x => (string)x.Element("name") == "title_en")
               .Select(x => (string)x.Element("a"))
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I prefer to use XPath expressions.